# Programs are no longer being recognized in ZSH

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, neovim

So I was organizing my dotfiles and moving some things around and ZSH is all of the sudden not recognizing various programs I have installed, and it's highlighting is no longer working. For example, HomeBrew and Neovim are no longer recognized (nvim and brew commands do not work). I wish I had more to provide you guys with as far as troubleshooting.. But I really don't know where to begin. My ZSHRC is still being sourced and run correctly, so there is no issue there. But I obviously changed something some where. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I somehow removed usr/local/bin from my PATH. This is where homebrew and nvim are. I never touched my PATH so i'm not sure how this happened.

However, I still don't have any shell highlighting. Any insight as to what might have happened is greatly appreciated.